# How to have better depth/disparity map image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, depth, disparity-mapping

I just obtained my depth map from 2 stereo cameras. 
I would like to obtain a better image but I don't know how to proceed. 
In this image i have already applied Calibration and Gaussian filter like this:

```
grayLeft = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.GaussianBlur(cv2.equalizeHist(grayLeft), (7,7),0))
grayRight = cv2.pyrDown(cv2.GaussianBlur(cv2.equalizeHist(grayRight), (7,7),0))
```

[image: this is my depth map starting from a resolution of 320x140]